# FreeRTOS library (AVR_ATmega328PB_Xplained_mini_GCC) versus FreeRTOS for Arduino boards

Tags: arduino-uno, atmega328

I am researching different IoT development boards and found that Espressif uses the IDF framework. When I looked at the source code it uses FreeRTOS libraries.

I have an Arduino Uno and I want to use FreeRTOS for programming it. I found that FreeRTOS has multiple libraries that support different microcontrollers. Arduino Uno has an ATmega328P and FreeRTOS [has libraries for it](https://github.com/FreeRTOS/FreeRTOS/tree/master/FreeRTOS/Demo/AVR_ATmega328PB_Xplained_mini_GCC).

I also found [libraries for the Arduino family of boards](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/libraries/freertos/).

What is the difference between these two libraries?

Comment: One is a demo, the other is a library. One is not for Arduino but for "bare metal" programming, the other is for Arduino. They're both FreeRTOS.

Comment: Thank you Majenko for the clarification

Answer (score 0):

**ATmega328PB** is not the same MCU as used by Arduino boards. Those use **ATmega328P** (no B). [ATmega328PB](https://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/en/atmega328pb) is a mostly compatible successor and offers more timers, built-in touch functionality and more but does not come in large DIP packages. Arduino uses the older [ATmega328P](https://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/en/atmega328p).